# Count each string in an string

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a text..

`text= ''' One of the best ways to make yourself happy in the present is to 
           recall happy times from the past memories '''`

I want to match each word in the match list and count their occurrence.

`match=['happy birthday to me' , 'john sent me the memo app' , 'self time' , 'call the rom']`

Example- In first iteration i.e, happy birthday to me...

**happy** is counted 2 times ,
**birthday** is counted 0 times ,
**to** is counted 2 times ,
**me** is counted 1 time. ('me' in **me**mories)

I want the result  as-

```
happy(2) birthday(0) to(2) me(1)
john(0) sent(1) me(1) the(3) memo(1) app(2)
self(1) time(1)
call(1) the(3) rom(1)
```

I tried this...

```
for textmatch in match:
    num=text.count(textmatch)
    textmatch= textmatch +'(' + str(num) +')'
    print(textmatch)
```

But this doesnt do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each word in the `match` strings. This can be achieved by splitting it (on spaces).

The other nifty trick is to print out each word with the optional `end` argument set to just a space (`' '`). This means that they all stay on one line until a plain `print()` call is made which moves to the next line.

```
for textmatch in match:
    for word in textmatch.split():
        num=text.count(word)
        print(word + '(' + str(num) + ')', end=' ')
    print()
```

Test in the interpreter:

```
>>> text= ''' One of the best ways to make yourself happy in the present is to 
...            recall happy times from the past memories '''
>>> 
>>> match=['happy birthday to me' , 'john sent me the memo app' , 'self time' , 'call the rom']
>>> for textmatch in match:
...     for word in textmatch.split():
...         num=text.count(word)
...         print(word + '(' + str(num) + ')', end=' ')
...     print()
... 
happy(2) birthday(0) to(2) me(2) 
john(0) sent(1) me(2) the(3) memo(1) app(2) 
self(1) time(1) 
call(1) the(3) rom(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension to form a list of words and their frequency:

```
text= ''' One of the best ways to make yourself happy in the present is to recall happy times from the past memories '''
match=['happy birthday to me' , 'john sent me the memo app' , 'self time' , 'call the rom']

print([[(y, text.count(y)) for y in x.split()] for x in match])
```

Comment: It works perfectly..  But can you make this more concise to read..Like happy(2) birthday(0) to(2) me(2)

Comment: @RaviSRanjan, If you have to do any manipulation on the result, you need to sacrifice the readability.